# SqlError due to single quotes around parameterized value for `CREATE DATABASE`

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

I'm using the "postgresql-simple" library and running into a SqlError with the following:

```
_ <- execute con "CREATE DATABASE ?" (Only ("example" :: String))
```

Results in an error of:

```
SqlError {sqlState = "42601", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "syntax error at or near \"'example'\"", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}
```

With the db logs being:

```
[postgres-db-b6f75998b-5qnnx db] 2019-12-28 12:28:40.062 UTC [100] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'example'" at character 17 
[postgres-db-b6f75998b-5qnnx db] 2019-12-28 12:28:40.062 UTC [100] STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE 'example'
```

Why are single quotes being added around the value?

Is this possibly due to postgresql-simple not using prepared statements?

Comment: I don't know anything about this library, but I would expect that `?` placeholders in queries are replaced with proper escaped and quoted strings to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://nikita-volkov.github.io/hasql-benchmarks/

> Unlike “postgresql-simple”, the library utilizes prepared statements,
>   which allows the database to parse the SQL statements only once per
>   connection.

So I wrongly assumed postgresql-simple would be using prepared statements, and hence it'll add single quotes around seemingly any string value.